# When i set axios response in vue js i get an empty array in laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am trying to display results in my page, When i log response. I can see the response, I have tried passing the response to vue js data, but each time it displays an empty array

```
     var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            results: []
        },
        mounted(){
            var url = "{{ url('fetch/messages') }}";
            axios.get(url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.results = response.data;
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
```

I am trying to display the response in the page `@{{ results }}`

Comment: try to use `.then(response => {`

Comment: i have tried it still returns empty array

Comment: Are you trying to render the results in a vue template or in a blade template? You can't update a blade template after it has been rendered in this way.

Comment: I am trying to display in a blade template

Answer (score 2):

The reason your data is not getting added to the Vue instance is because `this` will not refer to the Vue instance inside a `closure` (traditional `function () {}`). Please have a look at [this article](https://javascriptplayground.com/javascript-variable-scope-this/) for more information on `scope` and `this` keyword in javascript.

Below I refer to `ES` quite a bit which stands for `ECMAScript`. Here is an [article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-ecmascript-cba48c73a2b5) to show the difference between it and vanilla javascript.

I can see from your post that you're using ES6/ES2015 syntax for your method definitions so I'm assuming you're happy with just using modern browsers for now.

If this is the case then you can use [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) to get past the scope issue:

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
    this.results = response.data;
})
```

---

If not, then as mentioned in the `scope` article above, you would need to assign `this` to a variable:

```
var self = this;

axios.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        self.results = response.data;
    });
```

If this is the case, then I would also suggest not using the ES6 [method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) either so change `mounted(){` to `mounted: function () {`.

---

Finally, if you want to be able to use modern/new javascript e.g. ES6/ES2015 and above, but have your code work consistently with older browsers then I would suggest using something like `Laravel mix` to compile your javascript for you.

[Laravel Mix Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mix)
[Laravel Mix tutorial series](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-laravel-mix)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the following line of code, it will break.

```
            var url = "{{ url('fetch/messages') }}";
```